# Host a text file on WindowsCE using a web server

Tags: c#, webserver, windows-ce

Im trying to host a text file which can be viewed via a browser. This server will be running on a WindowsCE machine.

Currently when i try and view the file on my windows 7 machine using internet explorer 9 it works fine. 
Once i host it on WindowsCE internet explorer just sits there waiting with the working circle rotating.

If i run a telnet on port 80 to the webserver i can see my text file is returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

MyTextFileContents
```

Below is the complete method. No exceptions are logged and it logs "Finished serving log".

```
    static void launchLogWebServer()
    {
        new Thread(delegate()
        {
            LogIt(0, "Starting Log Server");
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 80);
            server.Start();
            TcpClient newConn;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    newConn = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                    LogIt(0, "Connection Made to Log Server");

                    NetworkStream stream = newConn.GetStream();
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

                    sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                    sw.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/plain");

                    sw.WriteLine();

                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()).Length != 0)
                    {
                    }

                    string text = string.Empty;

                    LogIt(0, "Reading Log File");

                    try
                    {                            
                        using (StreamReader logReader = new StreamReader("mylog.log"))
                        {
                            text = logReader.ReadToEnd();
                            logReader.Close();
                        }                            
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        LogIt(0, ex.ToString());
                        text = ex.ToString();
                    }

                    LogIt(0, "Completed Reading Log File");

                    sw.WriteLine(text);
                    sw.Flush();

                    newConn.Close();
                    LogIt(0, "Finished serving log");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    LogIt(0, ex.ToString());

                }
            }


        }).Start();

    }
```

EDIT: I should also note my WindowsCE is running .NET Compact Framework 2.0

Comment: Can you try specifying 'Content-Length' in HTTP header?

Comment: Bingo. Thats Yogee. Can you change your comment to an answer so i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 'Content-Length' parameter in HTTP header.